# Chrome "add to taskbar" icons are just capital letters

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, icons, start-screen

You know how through Chrome menu > More tools > Add to taskbar... you can add websites to a Start menu entry, and then pin them to the Start screen, desktop, and taskbar?

The icons of most websites (except Toggl and Instagram) I add to Start just end up as a white capital letter with a colored background. Like this:

[image: Google Calendar tile]

When I search for the application in Search though, they have a neat icon that's the same as the favicon. Also as in File Explorer (Open file location) and the taskbar. I've cleared my icon cache twice and nothing has changed.

What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably that the tile requires a larger icon than what the website's favicon supplies. It seems that as a fallback, for larger sizes Chrome generates and uses that letter-with-a-colored-background as an icon.

You could [use the Start menu](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-switch-between-start-menu-and-start-screen-in-windows-10/) instead of the Start screen to use smaller tiles/icons, or [manually change the shortcut's icon](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-change-icon-shortcut).

Comment: In my case I was failing to provide icons with enough size as you stated. I couldn't find this documented elsewhere, I was assuming Chrome would resize the nearest icon, but it doesn't. Thanks for this!